# Import new data into existing table access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Currently I can input excel data into new tables, but I would like to append the new data to the table everytime I select a new excel sheet? The code I am using now is shown below.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
On Error GoTo BadFormat
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Sample", 
fileName, True

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as of now, sadly it is **unclear what exactly you're currently asking** / what your code is supposed to accomplish

Comment: Actually this code works the table wasn't updating very quickly. All I was asking is how to have a table become populated with more than one excel sheet filled with data.

Comment: Yes, that was easy to figure out, me think. See answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to append records to the table, you should use your `ImportExcelSpreadsheet` function to import every time to a new temporary table.

After that, you could append all the content of the temporary table to the destination table, and then remove the temporary table:

```
' Import to temp table
ImportExcelSpreadsheet("filename.xlsx", "temp_table")
' Append to destination table
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO destination_table SELECT * FROM temp_table"
' Remove temp table
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "temp_table"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Link* the table:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, …
```

Then create an append query, that uses this linked table as source and writes (appends) your data to your Sample table.